# Output a pdf as PDF/X-1a:2003 using python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pyfpdf

I am building then saving a PDF file using the python fpdf2 library like this:

cli:

```
>pip install fpdf2
```

then in python:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF(unit = 'pt')

# <Add content to pdf>

pdf.output(<path>, "F")
```

However, I need the output to be in "PDF/X-1a:2003" (I don't even know how to check what type it is currently in).

Does anyone know to output the file in PDF/X-1a:2003 format using python?